# How can you send more than one Intent to the PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, android-widget, sharedpreferences

I have problem with `PreferenceActivity` used to set preferences for app widget. The thing is, that when I want to pass to the `PreferenceActivity` any info via `Intent` only at the first time I am able to read them. After when information sended in `Intent` are different, those earlier sended are still saved and I don't see new one. The only thing to do that is to remove completly app from system and install again. But then again everything will looks this same (first info will stay). The other important thing is that I am not saving it anywhere, just showing it in label text and in `LogCat`.

Those are code fragments responsible for this:

**Widget activity**

```
            // Actions required to open settings activity
            Intent intentSettings = new Intent(context, PrefActivity.class);
            intentSettings.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,
                    appWidgetIds);
            intentSettings.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, (allWidgetIds.length+number));
            PendingIntent pendingIntentSettings = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context, 0, intentSettings, 0);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imb_ustawienia,
                    pendingIntentSettings);
```

**Preference activity**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("Info","onCreate");

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);

        Bundle intentIn = getIntent().getExtras();
        Log.d("SIZE", "" + intentIn.size());
        if (intentIn == null) {
            Log.d("Tag","Intent is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            widgetId = intentIn.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            allWidgetIds = intentIn.getIntArray(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
            Log.d("Pref","id: " + widgetId + " ids: " + allWidgetIds.length);
        }

        final CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref1 = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("checkboxPref1");

//...

final Preference opt1 = (Preference) findPreference("settings1");
        opt1.setSummary("Widget's id: " + widgetId);

        opt1.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
//...
}

@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Intent infoIntent =  new Intent(DataAppWidgetProvider.FORCE_WIDGET_UPDATE);
        infoIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);
        this.sendBroadcast(infoIntent);
        finish();

    }
```

Do you know, what can be a problem? It looks like something is saved somewhere without my will and this is blocking everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems seems to be with the usage of pendingintent in your widget activity. Pending intents have the characteristic that if you send subsequent intents with the same intent attributes like requestcode, intent, etc, then even if you are adding new extras, all subsequent intents will actually be returning the same first intent. That is why you must be seeing that the data sent for the first time alone is reaching your preference activity and subsequent intents with different values in extras are having no effects. So if you want to use the same intent atributes to send updated extra values to preference activity , then you must be using some flags like `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to indicate that there are changes. Please read the [official document on pending intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) to understand this.